# Is it normal for there to be a small gap between toilet tank and wall?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, interior

We recently replaced the toilet in our bathroom and I'm noticing a gap between the tank and the wall. Example:

[image]

Is this normal?  Our last toilet tank was flush against the wall.

My concern is that people might lean back and place strain on the tank supports.

Comment: Leaning back isn't very conductive for going number 2 in my experience. It'll be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entirely normal. Among other things, the tank cover extends a bit past the tank so space has to be left for that. I'd be much more surprised if there *wasn't* a space there.

Answer (score 0):

That gap is why they first invented the skinny long-handle paint rollers.

You could get a piece of wood the proper size, paint it, then glue it to the wall behind. It could also have foam rubber (carpet pad) adhered to one side (against the tank). If the block had foam rubber on both sides, I dare say you could just friction-fit it and it should stay put.

Comment: Who invented it and how small was it?  The foam rubber pad - what do you do if you pee on it?

Comment: The skinny paint roller? Don't know who invented it but recall first seeing it sold as a behind-the-tank painting tool. Since then, they have taken many forms and are used for a wide range of things. They are about the diameter as a smoked sausage. If you manage to pee on a foam rubber pad, behind the tiolet tank, against the wall, I'd suggest you pee sitting down! :-)